# Retrofit generates wrong GET request parameters from Map<String : Any>

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I have following data:

```
var dict: Map<String, Any> = listOf()
dict["p1"] = listOf(1, 3)
dict["p2"] = listOf(null, 2.1)
dict["p3"] = 1
```

When I pass this data to following function:

```
@GET("uri?staticKey=staticValue")
fun testApi(@QueryMap(encoded = true) params: @JvmSuppressWildcards Map<String, Any>): Call<ResponseBody>
```

I expect the request URL to be:

```
uri?staticKey=staticValue&
    p1[0]=1&p1[1]=3&
    p2[0]=&p2[1]=2.1&
    p3=1
```

But here is what it produces:

```
uri?staticKey=staticValue&
    p1=[1, 3]&
    p2=[null, 2.1]&
    p3=1
```

Am I doing something wrong? I have just started with Kotlin and Android development, so I am not sure if this is supported by Retrofit/okhttp library.

**Note** I need such feature as `Map<String, Any>` in order to easily add/delete query params.

Comment: those array indexes which you'd expect make me wonder - just alike the actual output is obviously not a valid query-string... https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html ...this question cannot be answered, without the actual documentation of the parameters, which are being expected by the API; what you'd expect is rather irrelevant here.

Comment: a proper API might accept that as `JSON` posted as the body... because query-string is a) limited in length and b) it looks quite messy (far more complicated than it would need to be). however, the API dictates the outcome.

Comment: @MartinZeitler these array indexes are optional, with or without array indexes are both valid HTTP get request parameters, here is an example stackoverflow.com/a/3980336/1244597

You are correct about JSON in body as a POST request, but I cannot change my situation where I have to use a GET request, so my content-type cannot be JSON

Comment: it might indeed be theoretically "valid" ...but the API design is below standards (as the complicated way of building the requests might already hint for). if you have a chance to change the API, this might be a X/Y problem - if not, there's nothing to do about it.

Comment: in iOS I used Alamofire and SwiftHTTP, both libraries offer this functionality out of the box, this is really a common situation, here is a link of the above named libraries having this functionality https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP/blob/master/Source/Request.swift look for `extension Array: HTTPParameterProtocol::createPairs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution that offers

---

- Original keys in HashMap, so that updating/deleting is possible, such as

  ```
  dict.remove("p1")
  dict["p1"] = new value
  ```
- Ability to have nested arrays, such as

  ```
  [
    0: [coord1, coord2, coord3],
    1: [coord1, coord2, coord3]
  ]
  ```

---

```
data class URL(val params: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()) {

    override fun toString(): String = params.map {
        val value = it.value
        if (value !is Iterable<*>) {
            it.key + "=" + it.value.toString()
        } else {
            createPairs(it.key, value)
        }
    }.joinToString("&")

    fun createPairs(key: String, value: Iterable<*>): String {
        return value.mapIndexed { idx, value ->
            val useKey = key + "[" + idx + "]"
            if (value !is Iterable<*>) {
                useKey + "=" + (value?.toString() ?: "")
            } else
                createPairs(useKey, value)

        }.joinToString("&")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val url = URL()
url.params["p1"] = listOf(1, 3)
url.params["p2"] = listOf(null, 2.1)
url.params["p3"] = 1

val polygon1 = listOf("p1-coord1", "p1-coord2")
val polygon2 = listOf("p2-coord1", "p2-coord2", "p2-coord3")
val polygon3 = listOf("p3-coord1", "p3-coord2")
url.params["bbox"] = listOf(polygon1, polygon2, polygon3)

println(url.toString())
```

Output:

```
p1[0]=1&p1[1]=3&
p2[0]=&p2[1]=2.1&
p3=1&
bbox[0][0]=p1-coord1&bbox[0][1]=p1-coord2&
bbox[1][0]=p2-coord1&bbox[1][1]=p2-coord2&bbox[1][2]=p2-coord3&
bbox[2][0]=p3-coord1&bbox[2][1]=p3-coord2
```

Answer (score 0):

*Retrofit* just calls `toString()` on the value of the `Map<String, Any>`. To achieve what you intend, you have to define it directly

```
var dict: Map<String, Any> = listOf()
dict["p1[0]"] = 1
dict["p1[1]"] = 3
dict["p2[0]"] = ""
dict["p2[1]"] = 2.1
dict["p3"] = 1
```

You could map the map simply by just flattening it

```
fun Map<String, Any>.queryArgs(): Map<String, Any> {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
    forEach { (key, value) ->
        if (value !is Iterable<*>) {
            map[key] = value
        } else value.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
            map["$key[$index]"] = value ?: ""
        }
    }
    return map
}
```

This assumes only one level of lists at most.

Comment: Thanks for the overview on Retrofit's behavior.
This will create *different keys for each single parameter*, I also need the ability to delete an parameter from `Map`, e.g. deleting `p1` will remove all its elements, BTW I have updated my question, these array indexes are not necessary.
Thanks for your response!

Comment: Depending on the server setup these actually become necessary. Might be better to have. Especially when you use these as map keys. You could try to create a flat mapping you only apply in the end. Making your map into one with my values.

Comment: I did not quite understand what you meant *You could try to create a flat mapping you only apply in the end. Making your map into one with my values.* if possible can you provide a short example to start with, Thanks again for your response